# How to exclude posts from certain categories in Latest post

Tags: wordpress

I am getting the latest posts of all categories using the code below. 
I want to exclude 2 categories. ie latest posts should not include post of categories 1 and 3.

```
<?php 
$number = get_option('woo_tabs_latest'); if (empty($number) || $number < 1) $number = 5;
$the_query = new WP_Query('cat=' . $GLOBALS['featured_cat'] . '&showposts='. $number .'&orderby=post_date&order=desc');

while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;?><li>
<?phpwoo_get_image('image',48,48,'thumbnail',90,$post->ID,'src',1,0,'','',true,false,false); ?>
<a title="<?php _e('Permalink to ', 'woothemes'); ?> <?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<span class="meta"><?php the_time($GLOBALS['woodate']); ?></span>
<div class="fix"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can exclude posts by preceding the category ID with a negative (minus) sign.

```
WP_Query('cat=-1,-3');
```

Remember, the [WP Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Category_Parameters) is your friend.

Comment: $the_query = new WP_Query('cat=' . $GLOBALS['featured_cat'],-1,-3 . '&showposts='. $number .'&orderby=post_date&order=desc'); 
 Is this correct?